# FormatException in custom IUserPasswordStore<Client> implementation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, identity

I'm writing custom implementation of `IUserPasswordStore<Client>` but I got FormatException during login process.
It seems like method **GetPasswordHashAsync** or someone who call this method calls `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(String hashedPassword, String password)` which cause FormatException with message

> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

Here is my implementation of `IUserPasswordStore<Client>`

```
public partial class ClientRepository : IUserStore<Client>, IUserPasswordStore<Client>, IUserLockoutStore<Client, string>
{
    public Task CreateAsync(Client user)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Create(user));
    }

    public Task UpdateAsync(Client user)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Update(user));
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync(Client user)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Delete(user));
    }

    public Task<Client> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Find(userId));
    }

    public Task<Client> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(FetchOne(new ClientByUsername(userName)));
    }

    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(Client user, string passwordHash)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.Password = passwordHash);
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(Client user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.Password);
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(Client user)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password));
    }

    public Task<DateTimeOffset> GetLockoutEndDateAsync(Client user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<DateTimeOffset>(user.LockoutTo ?? DateTime.Now);
    }

    public Task SetLockoutEndDateAsync(Client user, DateTimeOffset lockoutEnd)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.LockoutTo = lockoutEnd.DateTime);
    }

    public Task<int> IncrementAccessFailedCountAsync(Client user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(++user.LoginAttempts);
    }

    public Task ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(Client user)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.LoginAttempts = 0);
    }

    public Task<int> GetAccessFailedCountAsync(Client user)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.LoginAttempts);
    }

    public Task<bool> GetLockoutEnabledAsync(Client user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }

    public Task SetLockoutEnabledAsync(Client user, bool enabled)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }



    public void Dispose()
    {
        database = null;
        Manager = null;
        context = null;
    }
}
```

And my question: Where is called Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(String hashedPassword, String password) and what should I return in **GetPasswordHashAsync**? 
For start I'm using password in plain text...

**Edit:** I thought, maybe I should provide some kind of hash service, so I add dummy implementation of IPasswordHasher for my purpose to use plain text

```
public class CustomPasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher
{
    public string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        return password; //return password as is
    }

    public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        if (hashedPassword.Equals(providedPassword))
        {
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
        }
        return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
    }
}

// and use it

public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<Client>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<Client> store, IPasswordHasher hasher)
        : base(store)
    {
        // ...
        PasswordHasher = hasher;
    }
}
```

but breakpoints inside CustomPasswordHasher weren't hit, so propably I'm missing something...

Comment: are you missing the following in that method `return await Task.FromResult(user.Password);`

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it doesn't help; still same exception... :/

Comment: have you stepped through the code using the debugger..?

Comment: Ofc. Have you got any specific question?

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed.** I was right with to use `CustomPasswordHasher`, but I had bug in Unity composition root. lol